# Chrome debugger continues automatically

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome, javascript-debugger

I have a **debugger statement** (i.e. `debugger;`) in my javascript code and the chrome debugger halts correctly, but then it just continues, but breaks at the next breakpoint. What the hell is wrong with it/me?

Thanks
Chris

Comment: after the first halt, do you press "play" in the top right corner or it goes by himself?

Comment: I thought automatically was clear enough ... sorry. It continues with **NO** interaction of me **at all**.

Comment: If you put a `debugger;` line in your code, does it break then?

Comment: Maybe you mistakenly use the F8 key e.g. when switching from console/editor/whatever? Or other conflicting keystroke? Or it's just a bug :P

Comment: I am pressing F5 to reload the page and then no physical interaction with the computer at all. The debugger console is already opened.

Comment: Toggle (activate & deactivate) the "Deactivate all breakpoints" button then see what happens...

Comment: No change in behavior ...

Comment: The last 2 options :- Plan Y..Restart Chrome, if that fails Plan Z...try uninstall/reinstall/Upgrade chrome.

Comment: Haha, did the former. Won't do the latter :D

Comment: Good show Mr Coxer! btw..a +1 on me rep wouldn't hurt ;)

Comment: With what justification? Can't find anything good about your comments, except that they are kinda funny.